# How to set time window in google or-tools vrptw?

Tags: or-tools

I am solving the VRPTW in Python

This is my time Matrix obtained from my coordinates:

```
  0     1     2     3     4    5
```

0     0  1130  1206   635  1072  977
1  1142     0   242   537   608  253
2  1225   156     0   658   645  409
3   808   781   856     0  1014  588
4  1248   686   703  1012     0  720
5   990   441   545   618   426    0

How to set time windows for my clients. Eg.

Depot - Time Window (4:30 AM to 9:30 AM) 
Loc1 - Time Window (5:00 AM to 9:00 AM)
Loc2 - Time Window (5:00 AM to 7:00 AM)
Loc2 - Time Window (5:00 AM to 7:00 AM)
Loc4 - Time Window (5:00 AM to 6:00 AM)

```
def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['time_matrix'] = [[0, 1130, 1206, 635, 1072, 977, 1315], [1142, 0, 242, 537, 608, 253, 257], [1225, 156, 0, 658, 645, 409, 105], [808, 781, 856, 0, 1014, 588, 927], [1248, 686, 703, 1012, 0, 720, 664], [990, 441, 545, 618, 426, 0, 506], [1194, 51, 181, 588, 561, 304, 0]]

    data['time_windows'] = [
        (0, 5),  # depot
        (7, 12),  # 1
        (10, 15),  # 2
        (16, 18),  # 3
        (10, 13),  # 4
        (0, 5),  # 5
        (5, 10)  # 6
    ]
    data['num_vehicles'] = 2
    data['depot'] = 0
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! The times in both `time_matrix` and `time_windows` are not tied into a certain time unit (such as minutes or hours). Therefore, if the values in `time_matrix` are of certain unit, the values in `time_windows` should have the same.

In your example you could scale the wall clock times to the same time unit you have in your `time_matrix` starting from the first possible time of departure at depot. Note that the solver expects the depot to have time constraints too.

I suppose you've read [this OR-tools example](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw) in which the example refers — misleadingly — to the time units both as "units" and "minutes".

I hope this helps!